# Textboxes comparing value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two textboxes and a script for comparing the value of both textboxes. Textbox2 field value is came from database. Textbox1 should not greater than textbox2 or value is 0. But the problem is sometimes textbox2 value is 0 came from database.

What I need to do is, if textbox2 is 0 allow the textbox1 to input 0. Any help will appreciate.

Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N2npz/

```
if (qty == "") {
    $("span.val_qty").html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
    validation_holder = 1;
} else if (+textBox1 > textBox2) {
    $('#txtbox1').val('');
    $("span.val_qty").html("Check the remaining Qty.").addClass('validate');
    validation_holder = 1;
    return false;
} else if (textBox1 == 0) {
    $('#txtbox1').val('');
    $("span.val_qty").html("Not Allowed.").addClass('validate');
    validation_holder = 1;
    return false;
} else {
    $("span.val_qty").html("");
}
```

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/N2npz/4/

Comment: @AmitKumar isn't working

Comment: you want when ever the value of textbox2 is 0 then textbox1 can have only 0. am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the value to int before comparing them. like this:

```
parseInt(textBox1,10)
```

Comment: No. He compare without type `==` not `===`.

Comment: He need to parse the values first. `val()` returns data in string type.

Comment: Whenever you suggest `parseInt`, Always suggest to use `radix` as well. like `parseInt(textBox1, 10)` here `10` for decimal number.

Comment: @Satpal: you are right..its good practice to use numeral system while parsing.

Comment: I am not sure why quantity will come as float

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Can you make a fiddle for this?